# Manually search and install WiFi driver

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, kernel, network-manager

I have a MSI Prestige 14 in which I'm installing Ubuntu 22.04. However, both the live session and the installed OS seem to not find my WiFi card and only Ethernet conection options are aviable. The question is so because I recieved the laptop with openSUSE Tumbleweed and WiFi was working with no issues. So I guess is about the driver not being present in the kernel? Tumbleweed kernel version was 6.3.9 at the begining and as far as I know Ubuntu 22.04 uses the 5.15 LTS kernel.

Output of `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`:

```
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi [8086:51f0] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Ethernet
    Subsystem: Rivet Networks Device [1a56:1671]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi, wl
```

Output of `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`:

```
[    4.775659] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.778933] iwlwifi: No config found for PCI dev 51f0/1671, rev=0x370, rfid=0x2010d000
[    4.778948] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:00:14.3 failed with error -22
```

How can I search/download and install such drivers?

Comment: First, open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+t) and run: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Next, edit your question to show the result.

Comment: Connect to the internet using ethernet. Open Additional drivers in software & updates. Does it list the wifi driver?

Comment: A built-in driver, `iwlwifi` claims your device. Let's see what the message log says: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: @chili555 output is updated. About adicional software & uptades: all I get is NVIDIA drivers

Comment: "No config found for PCI dev 51f0/1671" Please check the duplicate.